# Increasing the number of frames decreases the duration of video in opencv videowriter?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have a folder which contains multiple image files. I am combining them to write a video in 15fps. The problem is that for some reason, the size of final video, which is output is not increasing.
The code is as shown:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
for filename in glob.glob('/mnt/d/projects/sample_vids/*.jpeg'):
    print("h1")
    for i in range(1440):
        print(i)
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        height, width, layers = img.shape
        # size = (width, height)
        # dim_width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        # dim_height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        # dim = (dim_width, dim_height)

        resized = cv2.resize(img, (size[0] + i, size[1] + i), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        out.write(resized)
out.release()
```

In the above code, changing 1440 to 120, results in almost the same time as before. Not sure, where I am making a mistake

Comment: did you delete `project.avi` before running code? Maybe it didn't create new file or it created it in different place and you play again the same old video.

Comment: why do you resize `img` using variable `i` ? If you will try to write frame with wrong size then it will not write it. All `img` have to have the same size which you have in variable `size` in `VideWriter(... , size)` or you have to crop `img` to this `size` before `write()`

Answer (score 2):

- 1. Collect all the images using `glob`

  ```py
  import cv2
  import glob 

  img_array = []
  for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob('/mnt/d/projects/sample_vids/*.jpeg')):
      img = cv2.imread(filename)
      height, width, layers = img.shape
      size = (width, height)
      resized = cv2.resize(img, (size[0] + i, size[1] + i), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
      img_array.append(resized)
  ```
- 2. Init. `VideoWriter`

  ```py
  out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
  ```
- 3. Create Video

  ```py
  for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
  out.release()
  ```